# Boot Camp and Intel HD Audio

Tags: macos, audio, bootcamp, windows

I've recently encountered an interesting audio problem, using OS X with a Windows partition (via Boot Camp).  Specifically, if the Windows partition is used, and then the computer is restarted into OS X, the sound no longer works *in OS X*.  Once OS X has been restarted, the audio once again works.  The audio always seems to work on the Windows side.

**Further Clarification**
When the audio isn't working in OS X:

- the speaker icon in the menubar is grayed out
- if you go to Sound preferences, no output devices are available
- System Information, under the Audio tab, shows a list of outputs under "Devices", but nothing under "Intel High Definition Audio" (when functioning normally, after the OS X side has been restarted, there are a number of sub-options, including "Headphones", "Line Output", etc.)

**Replication** Scenarios causing audio loss:

Boot OS X : Audio works → Reboot OS X : Audio works → Repeat (Audio always works)

Boot Windows : Audio works → Reboot Windows : Audio works → Repeat (Audio always works)

Boot Windows : Audio works → Boot to OS X : Audio **doesn't work** → Reboot OS X : Audio works

Boot Windows : Audio works → Boot to OS X : Audio **doesn't work** → Boot to Windows : Audio works → Boot to OS X : Audio **doesn't work**

**Relevant System Information**

```
Mac Pro 4,1
Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Windows 8.1 (Preview)
```

I understand that Windows 8.1 isn't officially supported by Boot Camp and whatnot, but I'm actually kind of curious what is causing this to happen.

Comment: To properly research this, it would be great to search Event Viewer in Windows and paste any relevant errors related to audio you may see into this thread. I would also do the same in Console on the Mac.

Comment: Personally this sounds like an issue with the driver provided by Boot Camp, which hasn't been tested against Windows 8.1 probably. One thing to try: on Windows, open **Device Manager**. Locate the audio device. Right-click and "Uninstall". Check the box to "delete the driver software". Then go to **Action > Scan for Hardware Changes**. Allow Windows Update to search for the driver. If that fails, locate the driver on Intel's site and install it from there. See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, a workaround that would probably fix the issue is to [reset PRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) when you restart your system. This probably isn't very ideal however as it resets other video and audio settings as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that once I get access to the machine again.  I didn't even really consider that a driver could have effects across operating systems, but that would probably be a good explanation.

Comment: Hmmmm, when I run Uninstall from Device Manager, no "Delete the Driver Software" option is given.  When I scan for hardware changes, the old drivers pop right back up again.

Comment: Well, I downloaded a new driver, and it seemed to work once, but now it's stopped working again.  Maybe I'm still not quite sure what's causing the problem...

Comment: Sorry, I told you how to do it in Windows 7 on accident. Windows 8: Open Device Manager. Select device. Right-click > Properties. Click "Uninstall". This should accomplish the same thing. Without removing the bad driver, your system is probably reverting back to the old copy, hence the issue is returning.

Comment: Beyond this suggestion, you'll need to hope for a Windows 8 guru. Our company isn't supporting it, so I haven't used it much beyond the basics yet.

Comment: Huh.  Alright, maybe I'll just wait until 8.1 is officially released in the fall.  Thanks.